# React - multiple properties on an inline style for filter

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible for the `filter` property, applied to a `styles` object in React to have multiple filter values set?

```
saturation = 25;
blurAmount = 5;
brightness = 25;
opacity = 0.85;
let styles = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
    WebkitFilter: `brightness(${brightness}%) saturation(${saturation}%) blur(${blurAmount}px)`,
    filter: `brightness(${brightness}%) saturation(${saturation}%) blur(${blurAmount}px)`,
    opacity: opacity
};
```

In the code above, only the `opacity` and `backgroundImage` properties get set correctly when I add the inline style to my component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if react at the time supported setting multiple values, but the current version does.

Given that the filter value is just a string, I think it may have been able to back then as well.

It seems that your filter didn't render properly because you misspelled `saturate` as `saturation`.
After fixing that it displays correctly.

```
let saturation = 25;
let blurAmount = 5;
let brightness = 25;
let styles = {
    WebkitFilter: `brightness(${brightness}%) saturate(${saturation}%) blur(${blurAmount}px)`,
    filter: `brightness(${brightness}%) saturate(${saturation}%) blur(${blurAmount}px)`
};
```

Answer (score 2):

React does not support all the CSS properties so my best suggestion is you can use 3rd party library like this one https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-color-matrix-image-filters#supported-filters

checkout this lib I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I a solution I found was to give the element an `ID`, and set the `ID` to something that's associated with the color.

Example:

```html
 <img id={Log.serv} src="RadioWaves.png"/>
```

Log is a variable, that has dynamic input. Serv being severity (the color).

Now what you can do is on a CSS sheet, you can apply the filter to elements that have that `ID`.

Example:

```css
#AllSystemsGo{
    filter: invert(95%) sepia(79%) saturate(992%) hue-rotate(33deg) brightness(103%) contrast(98%);
}
```

You could substitute an `ID` with a separate `classname`, either way, works. I did not want to install a separate lib, so this what I came up with.